# Add the list1 in list 2 with same header vertically

Tags: python, dataframe, append, extend

I have many lists in Excel tabs with the same header, I want to combine it together however when I use list.append and list.extend syntax it combines horizontally not vertically as I want.

```
L1 = [1,2,3]
L2 = [4,5,6]

Expected output 
L = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6]]
```

Comment: `L = [L1, L2]` ?

Comment: There's no horizontal and vertical append in `lists`. It's just plain append. What do you exactly want?

Comment: Why is pandas tagged here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make an outer list...

```
list_of_lists = []
list_of_lists.append(L1)
list_of_lists.append(L2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
np.array(df['col'].values.tolist())
```